# My site goes pixels down when I use margin-top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add code to my site's body but the header just keeps going down whenever I put anything with margin-top, even having ended it.

Already tried to move the header to after the div logo and after the menu. It seems to work better when its after menu. When I had margin-top in `#barra`, it moves the whole header alongside with it. Already tried everything I remember. Plus, before I close the header, it seems to be alright, but after I close it, it gets all messed up. I suspect it has to do with the menu. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

[Header structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lQQS.png)

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8bbfyds3/1/)

Code:

HTML

```
<header id="header" class="fluid ">

  <div id="mail"></div>
  <div id="logo"> </div>

  <!-- Menu -->
  <div id="menu">
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Corpo parte 1 -->
<div id="barra"></div>
```

CSS

```
.fluid {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-image: url(Imagens/Headercontact.jpg);
  height: 21px;
}

#logo {
  width: 220px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left: 162px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-image: url(Imagens/logo2.png);
  position: fixed;
}

#menu {
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-top: 190px;
}

#menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 57px;
}

#menu a li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  width: 65px;
  height: 29px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#barra {
  background-image: url(Imagens/semi.jpg);
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a demo which is shown your problem.

Comment: I think the problem is related to everything being started in the top line. But I still cant solve the problem

Comment: I understand but a demo makes easier to understand your problem and solve it fast. For example, you can use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for creating a demo.

Comment: You're likely not clearing floats in the right place. Try `overflow: hidden` on `#menu`.

Comment: @Shikkediel It makes no difference

Comment: @alirezasafian First time using that platform, Im not doing well with external images :x

Comment: You can link all your images to your website or upload them in third partly website and then link them in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks [There you go](https://jsfiddle.net/8bbfyds3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if I misunderstand the issue you're trying to solve, but have you tried:

```
header {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yea, but not much seem to change. I think the problem is solved already, but thanks for you colaboration

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `float: left` in your `.fluid` rule and set your "#menu" `margin-top: 0px;` and it jumps back up ... [an update of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/8bbfyds3/3/)

Further more, your menu's `ul` element look like this

```
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
```

which is really wrong, as it should look like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

So I recommend to do some clean up work and get elements correct coded, as these issues can cause very unpredictable results.

Comment: The menu with margin-top: 0px; seem really messed up. And about the <li><a>, it really gets all weird when i put the opposite. Im hoping it doesn't need to be corrected, but I'll take that in account

Comment: @SlamGouveia The <li><a> issue needs to be corrected as that is a non valid structure of the <ul><li> element. This link show a few ways how to use it: http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-simple-and-practical-css-list-styles-you-can-copy-and-paste/

Answer (score 0):

The divs are not stacking correctly in your page because some floated elements are not being properly clearfixed, causing the divs to float in into each other (in this case, your header and some inner elements). To fix this, I removed the `float: left` property from your `.fluid` class and wrapped your floated header elements inside a `.clearfix` class so they remain in a row.

**CSS**

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
}

.fluid {
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

#header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/1ijUhkZ.jpg);
    height: 21px;
    
}

#mailtext {
    margin-left: 450px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Adobe Devanagari";
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    
}


#teltext {
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-family: "Adobe Devanagari";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    float:left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position:absolute
    
    
}

#logo {
    width: 220px;
    height: 210px;
    margin-left: 162px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/6u97lQ7.png);
    position: fixed;
 
}

#menu {
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: 190px;
}

#menu li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:57px;
}

#menu a li{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    width: 65px;
    height: 29px;    
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu a li:hover{
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/IH2Zg9N.png);
    width: 65px;
    height: 29px;
    display:block;
    color: white;
}

#barra {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/S7Qt9Mn.jpg);
    margin-top: 190px;
 height:30px;
 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Cabeçalho e logo -->
<header id="header" class="fluid">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="mail"></div>
    <span id="mailtext">&nbsp; Email: hotelsolemar@grupofbarata.com</span>

    <div id="tel"></div>
    <span id="teltext">Tel: (+351) 289 580 080</span>
    <div id="logo"> </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Menu -->
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Serviços</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Galeria</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Notícias</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Sobre</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contato</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Corpo parte 1 -->
<div id="barra"></div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8bbfyds3/4/

Comment: Thank you very much. Im just starting my first project for evaluation. You were a big help. The .clearfix can't be inside #header? And what happens if it's deleted?

Comment: Hello @SlamGouveia, the `.clearfix` container is simply used to wrap floated elements. For example, if you have a couple of elements which you wish to have side by side, you would wrap these elements with a clearfixed container so they remain in a row. Here is an [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/) that explains the need for clearing floated elements.